# Typescript If statement with multiple value matches for the same variable

Tags: typescript, if-statement

Is there a shorter way to manage a list of matching values for the same variable in a Typescript IF statement?

```
if(X==5 || X==undefined || X=="") {
     //do something...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically, you can use `switch` instead of `if` to test for multiple values using repeating cases:

```js
switch (x) {
  case 5:
  case "":
  case undefined:
    // do something
    break;
}
```

But this is rarely done.

To programatically test for multiple values, you can put the values in an array and check that it includes your argument value using `indexOf`:

```js
if ([5, "", undefined].indexOf(x) >= 0) {
  ...
}
```

Note that this will create the values array each time, so if this check repeats you might want to create the array once, elsewhere, and reuse it.

```js
const values = [5, "", undefined];

// elsewhere
if (values.indexOf(x) >= 0) {
  ...
}
```

In fact, if the number of values to test is large, you might want to put them in a `Set` and check that it `has` them, as this is faster than testing against an array:

```js
const values = new Set(5, "", undefined);

// elsewhere
if (values.has(x)) {
  ...
}
```